# mySQL partition

Tags: mysql, performance, partitioning

I have osCommerce installed with a website that has 140k products and product_description table size is about **300MB**. Page load tooks 15 second to **20 second**, I cut the table to 100MB for testing purpose and now it seem it is working as normal.

So I decided to use mySQL partition and made

```
PARTITION BY KEY()
PARTITIONS 10;
```

After this change I tested it but no change.

Now I decided to split database table into 3 or more with names like below

```
 product_description1
 product_description2
 product_description3
 ...
 ...
```

Am I doing wrong? Why mySQL partition didn't affect the performance or speed? Please suggestions.

Comment: partitions only speed up performance if you select only rows from (best) one partition. if you select across all partitions don't expect speed up ... in fact it will get a little bit slower.

Comment: you should increase server RAM to speed up performance

Comment: For example  ;

`PARTITION BY RANGE (store_id) (

    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (6),

    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (11),

    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (16),

    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);`

if I try to find store_id 15 do i need to know it is located in p2 part instead searching all.

Comment: @SirRufo I guess i need to tweak query codes to suit partitioned table otherwise as you said no performance change. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't mechanically apply partitioning if you don't have a clue that will help. Do the usual stuff first: index tuning.

The gains you get from partitioning entirely depend on the query patterns. I suspect your queries do not benefit from it. But they surely would benefit from the right indexes.

Comment: I tested physical split and 100% worked but i wonder why not mySQL partition didnt work. So if i use mechanic partition i need to write new queries and php lines to pass search head to another partition if didnt return any result from current partition.

Comment: @WishtobeNothing give up partitioning. It is not what you need. Use indexing.

Comment: Do you mean query split instead whole row result using index unique key

Comment: @WishtobeNothing I do not understand this sentence... Query split? Whole row result? Index unique key?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are very intentional and clever about your partitioning schema, you will *hurt* performance, rather than help it, by introducing partitions.

The first thing you need to do when trying to improve performance, is analyze your queries.  By doing this, you will probably find that you can get the performance gains you need with some index tweaks, and/or some server configuration tweaks.

300mb is not a very large table.  But depending on your queries, it may be slurping large amounts of your table into memory.  If your MySQL memory parameters are not properly tuned, you may be swapping to disk prematurely, thus making your queries very slow.